# Allowing user to resize image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I included an image in a XAML page dynamically:

```
<Image MaxHeight="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Uniform"
       Source="{Binding Image.ImageData, Converter={StaticResource ImageByteConverter}}"
       MouseWheel="Image_MouseWheel" />
```

Now I would like to allow the user to resize the image, if possible by means of drag and drop. How can I do that?

Comment: _means of drag and drop_ means?

Comment: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/12/let-user-move-resize-rectangle-wpf-c/

Comment: By dragging the sides?

Answer (score -1):

Put the image under the canvas.Bind the Canvas height and width to the **PointerPoint** object

Comment: reason for downvoting ?

Comment: probably because of the poor explanation, could you elaborate a little more for people not so expert at WPF?